# Hidden fastboot mode or no fastboot?

Tags: fastboot

So here is my problem: I cant get in to fastboot mode on my wiko tommy 3 android 8.1.0

Here is what I'm doing:

adb and fastboot are installed on pc (windows)
I have developer options and OEM bootloader unlock enabled
In terminal adb devices shows my phone
I enter adb reboot-bootloader but it does not say "fastboot mode" on screen like I have read it is supposed to. It just restarts my phone. ( note I have tried variations like reboot_bootloader; same result).
W
So my question is am I doing it wrong or is fastboot not on this phone. Or is it hidden somehow?

Comment: enter [recovery](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/wiko/wiko-tommy-3/recovery-mode) mode, from there select *reboot to bootloader*